# storing data on a server from an app

Tags: iphone, json, mamp

How does one store data on a server from an iOS app?

If I create, e.g. a JSON object, how can I send this to the server and save it on the server as the value from some Key?

I am using MAMP at the moment and have seen examples of how to create the item on the server and get it to the phone, I would like to learn how to create objects on the device, send them to the server for storage. such as a JSON object and store it on the server as a value for e.g. a key with an ID.

I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `NSUrlConnection`. Using it you can synchronously & asynchronously transmit data to your server using a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). It can GET/POST from a URL asynchronously and for storage, if the data set is small enough look at [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

On the server side (if the scripts are PHP), you can handle the data in the $_POST and $_GET variables just as if they were populated from the web.

If you wanted you could post the variables individually in their own $_POST or $_GET variables, or as 1 JSON string which you could [decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) when you receive it.

Comment: The iphone part I'm aware of. The server side is what I am unsure of. Does a php script need to be written to handle the POST and store it? Obviously if I ask, how does one write a php script, I will be given a link to php. I have pretty much zero experience with PHP, Are there scripts available to handle this that one can purchase, or how would I be able to quickly learn how to write the server script to handle the POST and be able to store it in MySQL tables? I have experience with MySQL.

Comment: Can data objects be stored as values in tables, or where and how would I store a JSON object POSTed by an iOS app? I know the GET request requests a link to a JSON url and it gets returned. but, how does on store the JSON object sent from the first device to the server as a URL?

Comment: Updated my answer regarding more details on the server side.

Comment: The thing is I dont want to decode the JSON object when the server receives it. Not yet at least. I want to just store it on the server and get a handle to it, for the next app to request using GET.App requesting the day, sends a value to be matched on the server. such as an ID value, on the server, take the ID and return the URL to the JSON object. then the app uses that URL to get what it needs.

Comment: You don't have to decode it at that time if you don't want to. You can send the JSON to the server from the phone, save the JSON string into your mySQL table, and then retreive/decode it as you need it in PHP later.

Comment: Thanks. I am really new to the whole server side of things. Does a script need to be used to save it, or is it better to do it from the phone using queries?

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check out [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) which will make things easier when dealing with downloading/uploading/processing JSON.