# Uploading a file via an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios4, mamp

Actually i am just trying to develop Box like app for iphone for practice, u may look over the link given below

Here's [a link](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/box-for-iphone-and-ipad/id290853822?mt=8)! for example

The  application should be capable of uploading his files of format .ppt, .doc, .jpeg, .txt, zip, etc. Just for sake of sever i am trying MAMP,  How can I upload the data to my local server.

Comment: Please go through these links [link1](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=22090) [link2](http://bluemandala.com/buddypress-plugin/54/testing-local-mamp-website-on-iphoneipad-or-parallels/) [link3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063119/test-local-websites-with-mamp-on-iphone) [link4](http://nclud.com/sketchbook/view-local-websites-iphone-ipad/) [link5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741542/storing-data-on-a-server-from-an-app) [link6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114124/make-virtual-host-available-through-local-network-for-iphone) may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to figure out the server-end on your own, but I'm a big fan of using the ASIHTTPRequest library for this type of thing.  Here's their docs on how to upload data:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#put_requests_and_custom_posts

Comment: thanks sir, it seems it will really help...